# No Internet Connectivity in Windows 10 after uninstalling Comodo Firewall

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I had Comodo firewall installed on my laptop,there was some conflict after I installed avast antivirus software,most applications failed to launch.So I booted to safe mode and removed the AV and Firewall.
After doing this and connecting to a wifi network ,there is no intenet Connectivity. USB Tethering is also not working.

Tried network diagnostics tool and it identified some driver issues.

Reinstalled the driver,but it did not help.

Tried some utilities to fix internet connection,still no use.

What might have gone  wrong?

Please advice ?

Comment: I suggest using a Windows restore point before comodo install.

Comment: @Moab will doing this delete files I have created after I have installed Comodo.

Comment: I had issues with Comodo firewall over 8 years ago, never used their product since.

Comment: No, System restore removes no personal files, but I do suggest to back up important files before restore.

Comment: @Moab will try doing that ..

Comment: Check there are no remnants of a proxy set.

Comment: Comodo has borked to many installations of mine in the past, I quit using their software many years ago, evidently it still borks PC's it is installed on....

Comment: @Moab I had to reset windows to fix the issue.Also had to reinstall drivers and software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue today on Windows 10(1803). I tried different solutions like resting networking etc... All in vain.

1. Downloaded Comodo uninstaller from [here](https://malwaretips.com/threads/official-comodo-uninstaller-v2-0-0-3-released.77722/). (Direct links [32bit](http://download.comodo.com/cis/download/installs/ciscleanuptool/ciscleanuptool_x86.exe), [64bit](http://download.comodo.com/cis/download/installs/ciscleanuptool/ciscleanuptool_x64.exe))
2. Boot up in safe mode and ran Comodo Internet Security Uninstaller (for me in normal mode it caused death screen)
3. Bootup in normal mode (Comodo Internet Security Uninstaller will automatically start and remove some other stuff)

Answer (score 0):

> After doing this and connecting to a wifi network ,there is no intenet Connectivity

If you have Windows 10 Anniversary Update, you can reset your network completely.

Check this article for click by click instructions: [How to Reset Your Entire Network in Windows 10 and Start From Scratch](https://www.howtogeek.com/265870/how-to-reset-your-entire-network-in-windows-10-and-start-from-scratch/)

Comment: Also reset Windows firewall rules. And check if Windows firewall service is running in services.msc

Comment: Tried resetting the network and restoring the firewall settings.The firewall is running.Still no internet.

Comment: I had to reset windows to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing you did and unable to connect the internet even I tried to reset network.

I found a perfect solution myself.

https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/213965929-How-to-change-the-network-adapter-settings-in-Windows-to-automatically-obtain-an-IP-address-from-the-router

Try this link, follow it until you are in the "Ethernet Properties" page, select "Comodo Firewall driver" and uninstall it or you can just uncheck it and apply. Your network will be back online. =} You are welcome. Bro!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140261)